# How to rewrite URLs with .htaccess (removing id?=1)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've looked all over and have yet to figure out how to make this work, I'm sure it's very simple for someone who knows what they're doing. For starters, I have made sure that mod_rewrite is enabled and removing `.php` extensions is working so I know that isn't the issue.

Currently I'm working on a forum, and what I'm trying to do is simply remove the `?id=1` aspect of the URL, so basically making the URL look like such:

```
http://url.com/Forum/Topic/1
```

Instead of

```
http://url.com/Forum/Topic?id=1
```

`/Forum` is a directory with a document named `Topic.php`

My current `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "...so I know that isn't the issue" - so what was the problem you are having? There doesn't appear to be any code related to this in what you have posted?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how to display the page 

http://example.com/Forum/Topic.php?id=1
as
http://example.com/Forum/Topic/1

I've looked for solutions online and have yet to come across one where the same situation is applied, and just haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you've changed the URLs in your application to use `http://example.com/Forum/Topic/1` then try the following:

```
# Remove .php file extension on requests
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]

# Specific rewrite for /Forum/Topic/N
RewriteRule ^(Forum/Topic)/(\d+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [END]

# Append .php extension for other requests
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [END]
```

Your original condition that checked `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` isn't necessarily checking the same "URL" that you are rewriting to - depending on the requested URL.

> **UPDATE:** however how would I go about adding another ID variable, as in making `http://example.com/Forum/Topic/1?page=1` look like `http://example.com/Forum/Topic/1/1`

So, in other words `/Forum/Topic/1/2` goes to `/Forum/Topic.php?id=1&page=2`. You could just add another rule. For example:

```
# Specific rewrite for /Forum/Topic/N
RewriteRule ^(Forum/Topic)/(\d+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [END]

# Specific rewrite for /Forum/Topic/N/N
RewriteRule ^(Forum/Topic)/(\d+)/(\d+)$ $1.php?id=$2&page=$3 [END]
```

Alternatively, you can combine them into one rule. However, this will mean you'll get an empty `page=` URL parameter when the 2nd paramter is omitted (although that *shouldn't* be a problem).

```
# Specific rewrite for both "/Forum/Topic/N" and "/Forum/Topic/N"
RewriteRule ^(Forum/Topic)/(\d+)(?:/(\d+))?$ $1.php?id=$2&page=$3 [END]
```

The `(?:/(\d+))?` part matches the optional 2nd parameter. The `?:` inside the parenthesis makes it a non-capturing group (otherwise we end up with an additional capturing subpattern that matches `/2`) and the trailing `?` makes the whole group optional.

Comment: You're welcome. Just to add, your "redirect" that removes the `.php` file extension is a 302 (temporary) redirect. If you are sure this is working OK then consider changing this to a 301 (permanent) redirect by changing `R` to `R=301`.

Comment: Sorry to add to the post, however how would I go about adding another ID variable, as in making `http://example.com/Forum/Topic/1?page=1` look like `http://example.com/Forum/Topic/1/1`?

Comment: You can either add another rule or combine the two variations into a single rule. I've updated my answer.