# Changing GET in url with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Basically i have `http://localhost/s/item?id=1`

But i want `http://localhost/s/item/1`

Been searching around a while but can't find a way to do this exactly, is there an easy way to accomplish this? thanks

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: ^ I second that

Comment: my bad, am new.

Comment: You re-write the URL to the ?id= format before passing it to the php script as shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141261/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-htaccess-removing-id-1

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement a rewriting rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?s/item/(\d+)$ /s/item?id=$1 [QSA,END]
```

This also means that you have to change your application logic such that it actually uses those URLs.

Such rule can be implemented in a distributed configuration file, but if possible you should prefer to place it in the actual http server's host configuration. Various reasons for that.